# Mental Health Questions

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, off-topic, questions, flagging

What's the deal with questions like [this](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/43320/can-therapeutic-training-be-dangerous)? From the title it sounds like a real question about physical fitness, but to me it's barely even a question. Should questions like this be redirected to another site or something? There are an alarming number of people seeking advice about how to continue destructive behavior through exercise. These types of question can't really be answered here, (or on any other site I can think of). I have no intention of shaming people with mental health issues here.

Mental and physical fitness go hand in hand, but what, if anything, is to be done with this kind of question other than recommend seeing some sort of health professional?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I hesitated to close it and instead left it up to the community. I encourage people to use their close vote whenever they see fit. As a moderator, my close vote instantly closes a question, so I try to only use it for completely bonkers and way off-topic stuff.

A question of "is this mix of all kinds of regimens harmful?" and "is it safe to train for 5 hours in this way?" can be valid questions in isolation. But the first problem is that these questions have to be considered on a per-person basis, which only a doctor can do after running basic health checks. Secondly, as soon as you involve whether or not something is good for your mind, it's off-topic, and even more unanswerable by internet strangers.

Comment: I totally agree. The part about the actual exercise regimen in the question seems like an afterthought just thrown in at the end and not the main focus of the question, so to me it's pretty off topic. Just sounds like low key bragging about how much they exercise if I'm completely honest